# tratamiento de exepciones en grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

Tengo una clase programada en java en el Netbeans, cuando trato de utilizar la clase en el grails ocurre un error de tratamiento de exepciones.
Este es mi codigo:

```
    package cermine; /**
    * Created by  on 7/05/16.
    */


   import pl.edu.icm.cermine.*;
   import pl.edu.icm.cermine.exception.AnalysisException;
   import pl.edu.icm.cermine.metadata.model.DocumentMetadata;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;

  import java.util.logging.Level;
  import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Extraccion {
public static String Arreglo[];
public static int last = -1;



 public static void metadataExtraction(String Ruta) throws Exception {

    int cantPdf = 13;
    int CDV = 4;   //cantidadDiscosVirtuales = Formula = 4;
    int lotes = cantPdf / CDV;

    Arreglo = new String[cantPdf];
    for (int i = 0; i < CDV; i++) {
        new Thread(proceso(i, lotes)).start();
    }
}




public static void Extraccion(String i)  {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
            ContentExtractor extractor = new ContentExtractor();
            inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/paul/cermine/sample.pdf");
            DocumentMetadata documentMetadata = ExtractionUtils.extractMetadata(extractor.getConf(), inputStream);
            System.out.println("Pdf  " + i + "Annalizado");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AnalysisException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            }

public static Runnable proceso(int i, int lotes) {
    return () -> {
        for (int j = 0; j < lotes; j++) {

            System.out.println(j + lotes * i);
            Extraccion(Arreglo[j + lotes * i]);


        }
    };


}
```

Realice algunos cambios en mi clase relacionados con la JVM y el error ahora cambia

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: cermine.Extraccion.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:119)
```

Que puede ser?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que no puedes cambiar el código del `catch`? Yo creo que sí, y podrías utilizar `this.getClass().getName()` en lugar de `JavaApplication15.class.getName()`

Comment: Luggi tiene razón, por otro lado, ¿Por que no puedes cambiar el nombre del logger? eso solo significa que el nombre de la clase sera otro en el Log, lo cual seria correcto si la clase cambio de nombre, pues de otro modo el mensaje seria confuso para quien lo lea en el futuro.

Comment: trate con el this y continua lanzando un error 
        cermine.Extraccion.this can not be referenced from a static context

Comment: ¿Qué es `Extraccion`?' Al parecer no es un método, por ello el error. Y si es una clase, quizás debas hacer `new Extraccion`.

Comment: puedes mostrarnos como defines la clase en primer lugar?

Comment: el error es claro, no tienes el método `main` en la clase. para que sea ejecutable debe incluir dicho método.

Comment: como deberia hacerlo ?

Comment: Defines un método `public static void main(String[] args)` dentro de la clase y defines el código que quieres ejecutar